# Get values of checkbox to other page

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="thheader">Monday</th>
                    <th class="thheader">Tuesday</th>
                    <th class="thheader">Wednesday</th>
                    <th class="thheader">Thursday</th>
                    <th class="thheader">Friday</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
          <?php
          $available = array();
          while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3))
          {

              $dayt = $row3['day_of_week'];
              $times = $row3['time_window_label'];
              $tt= explode(",",$times);
              $available[$dayt][] = trim($tt[1]);

          }
      for ($x=0; $x<3; $x++)
      {
        ?>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <center>
<?php 
      if($available[1][$x] != ''){ 
      $counter++;?>
      <input type="checkbox" class="colour-button choice1 daypicker1" day="1" name="val1" value="<?php echo @$tt[1]?>" id="btn112<?php echo $counter;?>" /><label for="btn112<?php echo $counter;?>"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle hide12" id="chk-btn112<?php echo $counter;?>"></i>  <?php echo @$available[1][$x];?></label>
      <?php }?>
     </center>
   </td>
   <td>
     <center>
      <?php if($available[2][$x] != ''){
      $counter++;?>
      <input type="checkbox" class="colour-button choice2 daypicker2" day="2" name="val2" value="<?php echo @$tt[1]?>" id="btn1012<?php echo $counter;?>" /><label for="btn1012<?php echo $counter;?>"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle hide13" id="chk-btn1012<?php echo $counter;?>"></i>  <?php echo @$available[2][$x];?></label>
      <?php }?>  
     </center>
   </td>
   <td>
    <center>
      <?php if($available[3][$x] != ''){
      $counter++;?>
      <input type="checkbox" class="colour-button choice3 daypicker3" day="3" name="val3" value="<?php echo @$tt[1]?>" id="btn102<?php echo $counter;?>" /><label for="btn102<?php echo $counter;?>"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle hide14" id="chk-btn102<?php echo $counter;?>"></i>  <?php echo @$available[3][$x];?></label>
      <?php }?>  
    </center>
  </td>
   <td>
    <center>
      <?php if($available[4][$x] != ''){
      $counter++;?>
      <input type="checkbox" class="colour-button choice4 daypicker4" day="4" name="val4" value="<?php echo @$tt[1]?>" id="btn1032<?php echo $counter;?>" /><label for="btn1032<?php echo $counter;?>"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle hide15" id="chk-btn1032<?php echo $counter;?>"></i>  <?php echo @$available[4][$x];?></label>
      <?php }?>  
    </center>
   </td>
   <td>
    <center>
      <?php if($available[5][$x] != ''){
      $counter++;?>
      <input type="checkbox" class="colour-button choice5 daypicker5" day="5" name="val5" value="<?php echo @$tt[1]?>" id="btn1042<?php echo $counter;?>" /><label for="btn1042<?php echo $counter;?>"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle hide16" id="chk-btn1042<?php echo $counter;?>"></i>  <?php echo @$available[5][$x];?></label>
      <?php }?>  
    </center>
   </td>
 </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

It is inside a form, and when I click submit I want to be able to get the values that are in the form. The problem I'm facing is that my rows are dynamic, for example here is my outcome:
[image]
These are checkboxes, and the user is only allowed to pick one per day. However when I send the form this is how I tried getting the values:

```
$value1 = $_POST['val1'];
$value2 = $_POST['val2'];
$value3 = $_POST['val3'];
$value4 = $_POST['val4'];
$value5 = $_POST['val5'];

echo $value1;die;
```

However my output is only 5AM-8AM all the time, it is never 9AM-12PM even if I chose it. it is always the first time on the row. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't you create `name` dynamically?

Comment: No I have to keep them like this so the user only has one option

Comment: Yes by doing this your all check box will be unique and you can get their values using `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: I cant do that I need them to make the user only have one option

Comment: Are you using ajax?

Comment: Give a try to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552680/several-checkboxes-sharing-the-same-name)